# Sharing objects between multiple classes using base class

Tags: php, dependency-injection, abstract-class

This article is similar to my needs, but I'm more curious about a specific solution to it, and if it's a good or bad idea to do it. [Sharing objects between PHP classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819334/sharing-objects-between-php-classes)

Say, like in the link above, I have an object I want to pass to multiple classes, say a $db object.

Instead of using dependency injection and passing it to each method's constructor, is it ever a good idea to let all the classes extend a **Base** class, that stores the $db object as a property?

For example:

```
abstract class Base {
    protected static $_db;
    public function setDatabase( Database $db ) {
        $this->_db = $db;
    }
    public function getDatabase() {
        return $this->_db;
    } 
} 

class SomeClass extends Base {
    public function doStuff() {
       $result = $this->getDatabase()->query(.....);
    }
}
```

Which would mean all classes that extend **Base** need not worry about grabbing/checking/setting the $db themselves, as they'd already have that object as a property as soon as the class is defined.

I know dependency injection is the usual way to go, but is this ever a viable solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still have to set the db on each instance of the class - setting it on one instance doesnt set it on all instances... unless of course its a `static` property.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write static above! I am already using static on the real code. So you agree that it is an okay solution (as long as static is used)?

Comment: well i ont think i would recommend it... what if you have a couple instances that need to use a different connection? At the least you should be able to pass in a connection to each method that interacts with the db if you use a static... That said i have done it this way before, so i cant really fault you for it. I guess it depends on the complexity of you app :-)

Comment: Hmm. One solution could be to let the OtherClass override get/setDatabase to use it's own $db variable if needed. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

That is perfectly fine. I have used it before and never ran into any issues.