# Best way to share class instance between classes in PHP

Tags: php

What is the best way to share a class instance between two inherited classes?

```
// Let's create a main class that hold common methods and connects to the database
class MyApp {
    public $DB;
    function __construct () {
        // Connect to the database here
        $this->DB = new Database();
    }
}

// This will hold methods specific to the user management
class Users extends MyApp {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}

// This will hold methods specific for fetching news articles
class News extends MyApp {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Now, in my application I have page that displays both Users and News on the same page. So I do something like this:

```
// Instantiate the users class (this will connect to the db)
$users = new Users();

// Instantiate the news calls (PROBLEM! This will create a new db connection instead of re-using the previous one)
$news = new News();
```

I can keep the DB instance separate and then pass it in. Something like this:

```
$db = new Database();
$users = new Users($db);
$news = new News($db);
```

But now I'm passing this stupid $db variable everywhere -- which feels messy and error-prone.

Is there a better way to structure this? The ideal solution would look something like this:

```
// Instantiate a global class which will connect the DB once
$App = new MyApp();

// Reference sub-classes which all share the parent class variables.
// Unfortunately PHP doesn't seem to have sub-class support :(
$App->Users->someMethod();
$App->News->someMethod();
```

Comment: "I can keep the DB instance separate and then pass it in". That is the correct way to do it, especially from a TDD point of view.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sharing objects between PHP classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/819334/sharing-objects-between-php-classes)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve what you want, you could do it this way:

```
class Database
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo "connecting to database...<br />";
    }
}

class MyApp
{
    public $Users;
    public $News;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = new Database();
    }

    public function initialize(array $classes)
    {
        foreach ($classes as $class) {
            $this->$class = new $class($this->db);
        }
    }
}

class Users
{
    public function __construct(Database $db)
    {
        echo "users have now db connection<br />";
    }
    public function someMethod()
    {
        echo "hello from users<br />";
    }
}

class News
{
    public function __construct(Database $db)
    {
        echo "news have now db connection<br />";
    }
    public function someMethod()
    {
        echo "hello from news<br />";
    }
}

$App = new MyApp();
$App->initialize(['Users', 'News']);
// Reference sub-classes which all share the parent class variables.
// Unfortunately PHP doesn't seem to have sub-class support :(
$App->Users->someMethod();
$App->News->someMethod();
```

Of course it's just a sample, you should add more checking for this, output for running above code would be:

```
connecting to database...
users have now db connection
news have now db connection
hello from users
hello from news
```

However much better would be injection to MyApp constructor Database connection instead of creating new instance in constructor.

**EDIT**

As alternative you could pass Database to constructor and use of magic `__get` function so you could now use:

```
class Database
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo "connecting to database...<br />";
    }
}

class MyApp
{
    protected $data;

    protected $allowed = ['Users','News'];

    public function __construct(Database $db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function __get($name) {
        if (in_array($name, $this->allowed)) {
            if (!isset($this->data[$name])) {
                $this->data[$name] = new $name($this->db);
            }
            return $this->data[$name];
        }
        throw new Exception('No '.$name.' property!');
    }
}

class Users
{
    public function __construct(Database $db)
    {
        echo "users have now db connection<br />";
    }
    public function someMethod()
    {
        echo "hello from users<br />";
    }
}

class News
{
    public function __construct(Database $db)
    {
        echo "news have now db connection<br />";
    }
    public function someMethod()
    {
        echo "hello from news<br />";
    }
}

$App = new MyApp(new Database());
$App->Users->someMethod();
$App->News->someMethod();
```

and the output for this would be:

```
connecting to database...
users have now db connection
hello from users
news have now db connection
hello from news
```

Comment: That looks like it would be difficult/impossible to unit test.